# 502 bad gateway error observed intermittently in Openshift 4.5

Tags: openshift, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I am using openshift 4.5. I used service and routes and it is externally accessible. Application is working fine, but sometimes i am getting 502 error.
I am using ingress haproxy route.
Appreciate your thoughts on resolving this issue.

Comment: What did you try already? Did you look at logs / events somewhere for example?

Comment: I checked the application logs, there are no error log information. So I concluded, the request is broken before reaching the application. And 502 also says bad gateway, i started troubleshooting from proxy side. I haven't checked the proxy logs. Not sure whether it will be available.

Comment: @arunkum96, have you found out what was the issue?